# FTP Config using yaml file Mule4

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I have made a flow that works in anypoint studio for mule 4. I am working to take out my hard coded config values and move them into a config file. An example of the yaml config is below.

config.yaml

```
ftpconfig:
 host: "myhost.us"
 port: 21
 username: "myusername"
 password: "mypassword"
```

mule xml file section

```
<configuration-properties file="config.yaml" />
<ftp:config name="FTP_Config" doc:name="FTP Config" doc:id="c34a3fbf-b37c-4c01-a3e0-36a138810e0b" >
    <ftp:connection host="${ftpconfig.host}" username="${ftpconfig.username}" password="${ftpconfig.password}" port="${ftpconfig.port}"/>
</ftp:config>
```

If I move the hard coded values into the attributes everything works. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your config.yaml file is under src/main/resources

Also, make sure that all property values in config.yaml are enclosed with double quotes (including the port number).

If that does not work, please update your question with the error your application is generating while bootstrapping / executing.

Comment: Issue was port number didn't have double quotes around it. Thanks, first time configuring a mule project.